# Phonegap/AngularJS: Get lat/long from inside function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I am trying to set a couple of global variables from inside a function so that I can use the results in an Angular Ctrl.

I have tried everything I can think of and can't seem to get the variable outside of the function. I know this is probably something simple but just can't figure it out!

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
onSuccess = function(position) {

        lat = position.coords.latitude;
        lon = position.coords.latitude;
        // alert('Latitude: '          + position.coords.latitude          + '\n' +
        //       'Longitude: '         + position.coords.longitude         + '\n' +
        //       'Altitude: '          + position.coords.altitude          + '\n' +
        //       'Accuracy: '          + position.coords.accuracy          + '\n' +
        //       'Altitude Accuracy: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy  + '\n' +
        //       'Heading: '           + position.coords.heading           + '\n' +
        //       'Speed: '             + position.coords.speed             + '\n' +
        //       'Timestamp: '         + new Date(position.timestamp)      + '\n');
    };

    // onError Callback receives a PositionError object
    //
    function onError(error) {
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);

    // ??????
    console.log(getCurrentPosition.lat);
```

## EDIT: This is the controller

I need to get lat and lon in place of the current hard coded versions:

```
var app = angular.module('presto-map', ["ngResource", "ngSanitize", "google-maps"]);

    function mapCtrl ($scope) {

        // Initialise the map
        $scope.map = {
            center: {
                latitude: 53.58684546368308,
                longitude: -1.5543620512747744
            },
            zoom: 8
        };

    }
```

Comment: Which variables are you trying to expose and where exactly they should  be visible?

Comment: may be you are looking for $scope.lat ...

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to rich `lat` variable in console.log, then the problem is that your `console.log` is called before `onSuccess` handler.

Update:

```
var app = angular.module('presto-map', ["ngResource", "ngSanitize", "google-maps"]);

function mapCtrl ($scope, $q, $window) {

    function getPosition() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            $scope.$apply(function() {
                deferred.resolve({
                    latitude : latitude,
                    longitude : longitude,
                    accuracy  : accuracy
                });
            })
        }, function(error) {
            deferred.reject(error);

        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }

    // Initialise the map
    getPosition().then(function(result) {
        $scope.map = {
             center: {
                latitude: result.latitude,
                longitude: result.longitude
            },
            zoom: 8
        };
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrey - I understand that now. I have edited the question now to make it a bit clearer. I'm by no means an expert with JS (Obviously) - So do I need to set a function that runs through onSuccess first? Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: @T2theC Basicly, the only way - to call ```console.log``` within onSuccess.

Comment: @T2theC added example.

Answer (score 1):

Pass `$window` to your controller and set `lat lng` in your scope.

```
       $scope.getCurrentLocation = function () {
            $window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                $scope.$apply(function() {
                    $scope.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                    $scope.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
                    $scope.accuracy = position.coords.accuracy;
                });
                }, function(error) {
                    alert(error);
            });
        }
```

Else if you want to have some global variables in your app use Services to do so. In Service have all the global data and then access it in your controller by passing the service to controllers.

Comment: How does one set in controller + save into DB? 
For controller I think it goes like `geolocation().then(function(position){$scope.position = position;}, function(){$scope.message = "NA";});`? I think  `$scope.position` part is wrong or something. Also how to I save it if I have a `$scope.post ={lat: ?; lon: ?;}` how do I correct the 2 codes?